# Finding lists depending on their unique members

Tags: c#, list

I'm new to C#, i have a problem and can't find an answer on the site.I have several List and all of them contains 3 items.

```
List1  :  1  2 3         
List2  :  0  6 1         
List3  :  1  2 6
List4  :  6  1 2
List4  :  2  3 6
List5  :  6  2 3
List6  :  3  6 4
List7  :  4  6 5
List8  :  5  6 7
List9  :  8  6 12
List10 :  10 6 13
List11 :  4  8  6
List12 :  11 7 13
List13 :  5 10 12
List14 :  10 12 6
```

I want to select lists that contains unique numbers. The result should like this. I need to select List1, List7 and List12 since any member of these lists corresponds with each other. I tried some recursive loops but failed. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

```
---------------------------
1 2 3    4 6 5    11 7 13 
---------------------------
List1    List7    List12
```

Comment: And *What have you tried so far?* Show your code too.

Comment: My code is irrelevant because none of them worked and I want to change my approach to this problem. I just want to learn if there is a different method to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with this data:

```
var xss = new[]
{
    new [] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new [] { 0, 6, 1 },
    new [] { 1, 2, 6 },
    new [] { 6, 1, 2 },
    new [] { 2, 3, 6 },
    new [] { 6, 2, 3 },
    new [] { 3, 6, 4 },
    new [] { 4, 6, 5 },
    new [] { 5, 6, 7 },
    new [] { 8, 6, 12 },
    new [] { 10, 6, 13 },
    new [] { 4, 8,  6 },
    new [] { 11, 7, 13 },
    new [] { 5, 10, 12 },
    new [] { 10, 12, 6 },
};
```

Then this query:

```
var query =
    xss.Skip(1).Aggregate(
        xss.Take(1).ToList(),
        (yss, xs) =>
        {
            if (yss.All(ys => ys.Except(xs).SequenceEqual(ys)))
            {
                yss.Add(xs);
            }
            return yss;
        });
```

Will return this result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

well, list number 1 will always have new numbers... i'd create a auxiliary list of know numbers, iterate through the lists provided checking for matches against known numbers, if no match came up, add it up and reserve the list... pretty basic stuff... i believe there's a way to do it with LINQ too...

not going to post code because i believe this to be a homework... and we don't do other people homework around here...